# Increasing the space between tables columns

Tags: tables

First of all, apologises for the noob question. Second, I am aware similar questions have been asked but their solutions don't work for me unfortunately. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a table (markup below), which is rendered very tightly together, which is proving cramped and difficult to read on the document. How can I increase the column width explicitly?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
{\bf } & {\bf Classifier 1} & {\bf Classifier 2} & {\bf Classifier 3} \\ \midrule
{\bf F1-Score} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{71.75\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{74.30\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{77.86\%} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first line will space out the lines

the second line will space out the columns

`\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{30px}`

before your `\begin{table}`

(It works with `\hline`, I don't know from which package top/bottom/middle rule come from, hence my not testing it)